# MS Access select a field on Table 2 by looking up multiple fields on Table 1

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, `Table1` with these fields:

`year|month|scenario|currency|Amount`

`Table2` with these fields

`year|month|scenario|currency|foreign exchange rate`

I want set up a query to look up the exchange rate to use from Table2 with the criteria being year+month+scenario+currency from Table1 and then multiply that rate with Amount in Table1

Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Add both tables to a new query, and create a join on multiple fields by dragging each one from Table1 to the matching field in Table2.

Then simply add an expression to the query:

```
myResult: Table1.Amount * Table2.[foreign exchange rate]
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost agree with the above answer... if using the visual query designer then judy drag and join the appropriate fields like year and date, or whatever applies, then add in the next blank field, `Exchanged_Value: table1.amount * table2.[foreign exchange rate]` , that's the correct syntax for access.